# combination of passwords problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

A password must contain 2 numerals from the list {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and 2 letters from the list {a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D,e,E}. the first symbol must be a letter. symbols may be repetitive. how many passwords can be generated meeting those conditions?  a)1*e5 b)4e5 c)6e5 d)8e5 e)1e6

the correct answer is b how can this computed

Comment: @PeterForeman The OP means that one upper bound for the number of passwords is $20^4$, which is lower than $400000$.

Comment: What I want to know is., where did the number $400000$ come from?  The OP claims that that is supposed to be the final correct answer, though I can not think of an interpretation of the problem that would give that result without completely changing the flavor of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean that every password must be exactly four characters long, exactly two of the characters must be a letter from $\{a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D,e,E\}$, the remaining two characters must be a number, the first character must be a letter, and repetition is allowed.

- The first character must be a letter, choose which letter
- Only one of the remaining three positions will be a letter.  Choose which position
- Choose which letter occupies that selected position
- Choose which number occupies the left-most remaining position
- Choose which number occupies the final position

Applying multiplication principle, we get then a final total of $10\cdot 3\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10 = 30000$ possible arrangements.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But the correct answer is 400000! it is a test question and given answers are a)100,000 b)400,000 c)600,000 d)800,000

Comment: @engineer1155 Then double check the problem statement.  You must have written it incorrectly or left out certain information, such as "A password of length ____ is made using _____ such that ____."  My answer is correct for the assumptions that I have written.

Comment: @engineer1155 by your own logic, you correctly note that $20\cdot 20\cdot 20\cdot 20=80000$ is the number of four-character passwords using the available ten letters or ten digits with no other restrictions and that value is less than all of the answer options, so there must some mistake or miscommunication somewhere.

Comment: i have added the exact question.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think you mean $160,000$ but that is still smaller than $400,000$

Comment: @engineer1155 and I stand by my answer.  My answer is correct given the assumptions that I have listed.  An example of a similar question that gives an answer of $400000$ would be "how many passwords of length $5$ can be made where we use exactly two letters from `aAbBcCdDeE`, we use **three** digits, the first character must be a letter, and repetition is allowed."  For that, using the same logic as above, we would have $10\cdot 4\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10 = 400000$

Comment: @kccu yes, wasn't paying close enough attention there, but the point remains that the question as currently written does not have an answer of $400000$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you. Yes i also think the main question is wrong. Could you please edit your answer to general case of problems with these conditions (i.e. number of passwords of length L and a certain character must be a letter.)

Comment: @JMoravitz Speaking of similar question. Another question was number of passwords with 2 numbers and 4 letters with the same conditions(first should be a letter) according to your reasoning the answer is 10*5*10*10*10*10*10 however the correct answer is 10,000,000 or 10*20*20*20*20*20. I really get confused what is the correct answer??

Comment: @engineer1155 for that, it would be that you first pick the letter at the front., then pick which remaining position**s** are used for the letters in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, then pick the letter for each of those selected positions from left to right, then pick the numbers for the remaining positions from left to right, giving a total of $10\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdots 10 = 10^7$

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thanks :).